# Copy item from Org Agenda

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

For some reason I cannot explain, `org-copy` (`C-c M-w`) does not work from Org Agenda (mini-buffer saying `C-c M-w is undefined`).

`org-refile` (`C-c C-w`) does work from the agenda and `org-copy` as well from any other org file.

How to make `org-copy` work from the Agenda? Should I be using `org-agenda-write` (`C-x C-w`) to export a unique header?